# Laravel 10 groupBy column from another field

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I would like to groupBy all the contents of a table using a column from it's own table and from another table.

I have 3 tables (this is just a simple example but very similar to what I'm working on)

1. 1st table (homes) contains all the homes
2. 2nd table (fields) contains all the available fields to fill-up for the each homes.
3. 3rd table is a pivot table (home_fields) that contains the field_id with value for each homes.

**homes table**

| ID | home_name | home_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Home #1 | farm |
| 2 | Home #2 | farm |
| 3 | Home #3 | beach |

**fields table**

| ID | field_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Floor Area |
| 2 | Bathroom |
| 3 | Basement |
| 4 | Wine Cellar |
| 5 | Beach Access |

**home_fields table**

| ID | home_id | field_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 8000ft |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 9000ft |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 7000ft |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | Yes |
| 5 | 3 | 5 | Yes |

Now, I would like to retrieve all the data from the **homes** table.
Then group them according by **homes.home_type** and **fields.field_name** table based on the data from home_fields so i can display them as filter on the front page. Fields that don't have corresponding data in **home_fields** table are excluded and hidden in blade.

Expected output is this:

```
Filter by Type:
Farm  ---------------- (2)
Beach  --------------- (1)

Filter by Details:
Floor Area  ---------- (3)
Basement ------------- (1)
Beach Access --------- (1)
```

Another thing is performance. It should be light and fast to handle lots of entries. Must be done in one query as much as possible. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter data by parameter that request from FE, and get it at BE
`$param = 'homes.home_type'` or `$param = 'fields.field_name'`

```
$data = DB::table('home_fields')
        ->join('homes', 'homes.id', 'home_fields.home_id')
        ->join('fields', 'fields.id', 'home_fields.field_id')
        ->selectRaw("$param as columnA")
        ->selectRaw("count(*) as columnB")
        ->groupBy($param)
        ->get();
```

I hope it works!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I believe your query will only select homes that have field entries. What I wanted to accomplish is (1) get all homes regardless if they have or not have data in home_fields (2) the purpose of the groupBy is to create a filter on the sidebar so the user can easily click on them. I have no problem with filtering and grouping by column on same table. But the groupby from columns on another table, I'm having trouble figuring it out. Thanks.